# How to call all functions with common name to be used in CodeIgniter Unit Test

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for the rather poor title, but hopefully I can explain it with some code.

So lets say I have the following functions:

```
<?php    
function helloTest()
{
    echo 'hello';
}

function worldTest()
{
    echo 'world';
}

function helloworld()
{
    // call all functions with 'Test'
}
?>
```

Is it possible for the *helloworld* function to call all functions which are named at the end as 'Test'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$funcs = get_defined_functions();

foreach( $funcs['user'] as $f ) {
    if( strstr($f, 'Test') )
        call_user_func($f);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Get All methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php) php function to get all methods like below

```
function helloTest()
{
    echo 'hello';
}

function worldTest()
{
    echo 'world';
}

function helloworld()
{
    // call all functions with 'Test'
    $methods = get_defined_functions();
    $user_defined_methods = $methods['user'];
    foreach ($user_defined_methods as $method_name) 
    {
         //check with regular expressions if it's having 'Test' at end of $method_name then call that function using call_user_func($method_name)
    }
}
```

for more info check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php)